# BigQuery data transfer service from Google Ads - missing some columns

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

In Google BigQuery we have setup a data transfer from Google Ads. It's a very nice integration, but we do miss some columns about the so-called "quality score".

To be specific, we are looking for:

- HistoricalQualityScore
- HistoricalCreativeQualityScore
- HistoricalLandingPageQualityScore
- HistoricalSearchPredictedCtr

All from the report: KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT

They should be supported by the API ([v201806 reports](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/all-reports)).

Might i be missing something? Or would it make sense, to request this from Google?

Screenshot of the Columns from the official doc:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the ["Column mapping for Google Ads reports"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transformation#column_mapping_for_google_ads_reports), those columns are not included in the Google Ads Transfers. I specially checked the columns for the Keywords Performance Report but I don't see any related columns.

You may either ask the Google Ads team how to get those values from the data exported, or if this can't be obtained with the current columns exported, then [file a feature request to the Bigquery team](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685).

Comment: Thanks Neri. Good to know that i didn't overlook something obvious and very helpful suggestions for a possible next steps.